# Unable to set engine-strict flag with yarn

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, nvm

I am trying to force all devs to use particular version of node or higher.

I have

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14",
    "yarn": ">=1.5",
    "npm": "please-use-yarn"
  },
```

I tried

1. .npmrc

```
engine-strict = true
```

2. .yarnrc.yml

```
ignore-engines:  true
```

but it led to following error when I run `yarn install`

> Usage Error: Unrecognized or legacy configuration settings found: ignore-engines - run "yarn config -v" to see the list of settings supported in Yarn

How can I force devs to use particular version of node?

Answer (score 5):

Add `--install.ignore-engines false` in .yarnrc

tp4k answered this on [Github](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3282#issuecomment-429775852)

I have my `.npmrc` the same as yours and `.yarnrc` as mine. Node version is automatically checked too

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the below key value pair in package.json

> "engineStrict": true,

**Reason:**
The engine-strict configuration setting is specific to npm, and it's used to enforce strict compatibility checks between the Node.js version specified in your package's engines field and the currently installed Node.js version. When engine-strict is set to true in npm, it means that npm will strictly enforce the Node.js version compatibility, and if there's a mismatch, it will prevent you from installing packages.

Yarn does not have an equivalent engine-strict configuration setting. Instead, Yarn relies on the package managers specified in your project to handle compatibility checks. This means that Yarn will typically use the engines field in your package.json to determine which versions of Node.js are compatible with your project. If there's a Node.js version mismatch, Yarn may still allow you to install packages, but it's up to the individual packages and their maintainers to enforce compatibility.